# Unity persistent touch detection

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch

I'm having a problem on stopping my screen touch event, I have a button in it, once I hit the UI Button, it still detects a touch event on my screen, how am I suppose to stop making my screen touch event from doing this? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code for my touch screen:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {

   if (myTouch [i].phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

   } else if (myTouch[i].phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

   } else if (myTouch [i].phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
      // RUN TOUCH FUNCTION HERE
   }
}
```

and on my Button:

```
public void PauseGame(){

    //DO Pause game here

}
```

Comment: How have you implemented the button?

Comment: It's in the canvas, and it's onClick()

Comment: So it's using the NGUI APIs?

Comment: I don't know NGUI(Native GUI?) if that's it, Yes my unity is 5.2.1f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple create **bool** variable like "isTouchActive" set to **true**, than in on your button logic change it's state like:
`isTouchActive = !isTouchActive;`
In touch logic simply check this variable like:

```
if(isTouchActive)
{  
 for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) 
 {

   if (myTouch [i].phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

   } else if (myTouch[i].phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

   } else if (myTouch [i].phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
      // RUN TOUCH FUNCTION HERE
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks though, apparently it still detects the began and moved phase.